# Adding project folder to PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python

I am new to using Python via terminal. I would need advice with adding a folder to PYTHONPATH - I'm really happy if someone can help!

I try to follow the steps of this repo:

https://github.com/davidstap/AttnGAN

where project folder needs to be added to PYTHONPATH.

By googling, I found this suggestion and edited it to fit my current project folder location:

`export PYTHONPATH=/Users/MyName/Documents/Modules/AttnGAN`

However, if I just open the terminal, type that suggestion and continue with another piece of the Pytorch code it can't find the right file:

```
Last login: Thu Apr 16 15:41:49 on ttys000
(base) MyName-MacBook-Pro:~ MyName$ export PYTHONPATH=/Users/MyName/Documents/Modules/AttnGAN
(base) MyName-MacBook-Pro:~ MyName$ python main.py --cfg cfg/eval_bird.yml --gpu 1
python: can't open file 'main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
(base) MyName-MacBook-Pro:~ MyName$
```

So clearly this trial is not working - what would be the right way to add to PYTHONPATH? This is my first time approaching training in terminal so please bear with me!

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux or Mac, you need to add to the python path as follows:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/Users/MyName/Documents/Modules/AttnGAN"
```

Comment: Hi @ithomas, thanks a lot! I tried that with my Mac and it still complains about not finding 'main.py' so I guess it is about something else now. My Python files are otherwise in Macintosh HD/opt/Anaconda3/lib/python3.7 if that makes any difference

Comment: I checked and PyTorch is installed:
`pip3 install torch torchvision
Requirement already satisfied: torch in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: torchvision in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from torchvision) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from torchvision) (1.18.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=4.1.1 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from torchvision) (6.2.0)`

Comment: Hi vjuss, I don't know anything about your installation, so it's hard to know exactly what is wrong, but I would be careful with python versions. From your comment above you're running version 3.7, but then calling your script with python. Have you tried python3:
`python3 main.py --cfg cfg/eval_bird.yml --gpu 1`?

Otherwise check the new directory is present by running a simple script:
`import sys; print(sys.path)`

Answer (score 0):

Some updates: I added

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/Users/myName/Documents/Modules/AttnGAN"
```

to my bash profile by using open .bash_profile. Not sure this is what you meant @ithomas? Now `echo $PYTHONPATH` in terminal gives me the right AttnGAN folder. However, I am still not accessing pretrain_DAMS.py (or any other files) from that repo by typing, for example:

```
python pretrain_DAMSM.py --cfg cfg/DAMSM/bird.yml --gpu 0
```

I get "No such file or directory". This is really newbie question but: do I need to set up Python somehow when opening the terminal? Before writing any python commands?